# Change background image based on text in h2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an several pages with an h2 header that has a background image. How do I change the background url based on the text inside the h2?

if text = flyers use url1
if text = postcards use url2 etc.

I would like to build a function and just run the function the these 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function changeBackground() {    
        const h2 = $("h2"); // change with your h2 selector
        const text = h2.text();
        
        if (text === "flyers") {
          h2.css("background-image", url1)
        }
        else if (text === "postcards") {
          h2.css("background-image", url2);
        }
    }

changeBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Javascript for this particular scenario.

This might help you out -

```
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2'); // Your H2 element
const elemWithBg = document.querySelector('div'); // elem that shows backgroud

if (h2. textContent === 'flyers') {
  elemWithBg.style.backgroundImage = `url(/path/to/first/image.jpg)`;
} else if (h2. textContent === 'postcards') {
  elemWithBg.style.backgroundImage = `url(/path/to/second/image.jpg)`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is my site. 

https://megaprint.orderprintnow.com/ProductList.aspx?CatalogId=adb661a4-b8d3-4cc1-b98c-dc07f38b5a11&PortalId=e59f5f57-7973-466a-afbf-d11bfb2e5c56

My h2 is my BG image. This is what I have now.

$('.litHeader').text(function(i, currentText){
if (currentText == "Flyers"){
$('.litHeader').style.backgroundImage = `url(https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/2092/posts/35085/image/business_flyer_1b.jpg)`;}
}